# Salesforce Marketing Cloud, how do you name a report with todays date and/or rename files on the Enhanced FTP?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, reporting

I have set up a bunch of reports to run daily out of the Report Catalog for email.  There is an option for "name unique" but no options for naming with todays date.

How can i get these reports to have the date in exported report name on the FTP?

I tried added Ampscript to my file name (like in an import activity) and that did not work.  I tried to use the file transfer activity to rename the file, that did not work.

Any ideas on how to solve this?  thanks

Comment: I don't believe this is possible when you're using the reports that come out of analytics builder. In the legacy reporting this would have been possible through creating a report definition.

Comment: Thanks @NickHoldren i remember the report definition solution, which is why this current short coming blows my mind.